# Ubuntu 22.04.2 all USB ports suddenly stopped working

Tags: usb, 22.04

After leaving work on Monday, as usual, I closed my laptop (Dell Vostro 15 3000), when I came back the next day, I noticed the computer was off (the battery was not flat)  and I had to reboot. Since then, none of the 2 USB ports are working :

- None of the USB mice I tried produces any reaction, in fact they don't even turn on when plugged. They work as expected on other machines.
- If I connect my phone through USB, it does charge on both ports, but the system doesn't see it

I was previously using Ubuntu 20.04 and I thought an upgrade would solve the issue, but it didn't change anything. I'm now using Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS (5.14.0-1057-oem)

This is the output of lsusb, this output never changes whatever is plugged on any of the ports :

```
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub Bus 001
Device 002: ID 0c45:671e Microdia Integrated_Webcam_HD Bus 001 Device
003: ID 0cf3:e009 Qualcomm Atheros Communications  Bus 001 Device 001:
ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Also nothing happens with dmesg when I plug or unplug a device :

```
[    0.230537] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.230537] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.230537] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    0.570259] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.14
[    0.570266] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.570268] usb usb1: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    0.570270] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 5.14.0-1057-oem xhci-hcd
[    0.570271] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    0.580434] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 5.14
[    0.580435] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    0.580436] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    0.580437] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 5.14.0-1057-oem xhci-hcd
[    0.580438] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:00:14.0
[    0.581028] usb: port power management may be unreliable
[    0.918432] usb 1-6: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    1.163368] usb 1-6: New USB device found, idVendor=0c45, idProduct=671e, bcdDevice=85.02
[    1.163376] usb 1-6: New USB device strings: Mfr=2, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[    1.163379] usb 1-6: Product: Integrated_Webcam_HD
[    1.163381] usb 1-6: Manufacturer: CN0G4JK98LG000A4DRKSA01
[    1.290567] usb 1-10: new full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    1.439895] usb 1-10: New USB device found, idVendor=0cf3, idProduct=e009, bcdDevice= 0.01
[    1.439903] usb 1-10: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
[    2.512053] usbcore: registered new interface driver btusb
[    2.639020] usb 1-6: Found UVC 1.00 device Integrated_Webcam_HD (0c45:671e)
[    2.653390] input: Integrated_Webcam_HD: Integrate as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-6/1-6:1.0/input/input14
[    2.653455] usbcore: registered new interface driver uvcvideo
```

Restarting the computer doesn't fix anything (even temporarly).
During boot, the mouse does turn on, but it appears off once the grup appears

Any idea?

Comment: That is more likely a power problem then an OS problem.

Comment: just faced with exactly the same issue. Could you resolve that?